# Check existence of multiple IDs with Spring Data JPA

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

Analogous to the built-in method `existsById` I'd like to hava an `existsAllById` method with Spring Data JPA. To achieve this, I added the following method to the repository *interface*.

```
@Query(
  "select case when (count(thing) = size(:ids)) then true else false end " +
  "from Thing thing " +
  "where thing.id in :ids")
boolean existsAllById(@Param("ids") Set<UUID> ids);
```

However, Hibernate seemingly doesn't like my usage of `size` and reports me this error:

> Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unexpected expression ? found for collection function size [select case when (count(trhing) = size(:ids)) then true else false end from com.example.Thing resource where thing.id in :ids]
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException.convert(QuerySyntaxException.java:74)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.ErrorTracker.throwQueryException(ErrorTracker.java:93)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.analyze(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:282)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.doCompile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:192)
> at org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QueryTranslatorImpl.compile(QueryTranslatorImpl.java:144)
> at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:113)
> at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.HQLQueryPlan.(HQLQueryPlan.java:73)
> at org.hibernate.engine.query.spi.QueryPlanCache.getHQLQueryPlan(QueryPlanCache.java:162)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.getQueryPlan(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:613)
> at org.hibernate.internal.AbstractSharedSessionContract.createQuery(AbstractSharedSessionContract.java:725)

How can this query be fixed? What is the best way to check the existence of multiple IDs with Spring Data JPA?

Comment: `Boolean existsByIdIn(Collection<UUID> ids);`

Comment: That doesn't seem to work. If I'm adding a non existent ID, I'm still getting `true` as a result.

Comment: Oh sorry, I misunderstood, you want true only if all the id's exist, and false if some are not there

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can count the amount of found items and then compare that to the size of your input.

Note, use a Set<> here to prevent duplicates that'd ruin the count.

```java
Integer countAllByIdIn(Set<UUID> ids);

default boolean existsAllById(Set<UUID> ids) {
    return countAllByIdIn(ids).equals(ids.size());
}
```

Alternatively you can do, the key word being `existsAll`:

```java
Boolean existsAllByIdIn(Set<UUID> ids);
```

Comment: For some reason `existsAllByIdIn` returns `true` even if not all IDs are existent, but the first approach works fine!

Comment: @deamon That's because it checks if they all exist in the set of ids you gave. Let's say `existsAll` returns a set with id `1`. You supply a set with ids `1` and `2`. Then they all exist in the set you gave, because your set contains all of them, i.e. `1`.